# Javascript adding two times and checking condition

Tags: javascript, time

I am not able to add two times in java-script.I used code like this

```
var dbEndtime1 = new Date(dbEndtime);
var hours  = dbEndtime1.getHours();
alert(dbEndtime1 + " hours" + hours);
```

Its not giving hours

`dbEndtime="10:40:00"` I want to add hours to this and again coming value I need to check with `1:00:00.` Like `total-time=10:40:00+5hours`, `total-time>1:00:00` and `total-time<24:00:00`

I want to implement this logic. But I am not getting it done in java-script.

Comment: This makes very little sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
var now = new Date("2013/1/1 02:14");
now.setHours(now.getHours()+5);


alert(now.getHours())

if(now.getHours()==1 && now.getMinutes()==0 && now.getSeconds()==0){
  //It 's 1:00:00
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/2SLPm/

Comment: alert(now.getHours()) if i use this means alert it giving NAN